# Make MySQL LIKE Return Full Word matches Only

Tags: mysql, regex

I dont want rows to be returned where the LIKE is matching a partial word. I am splitting strings on whitespace and then generating a query that will find a match, but its returning matches for partial words. Here is an example

```
SELECT ID from VideoGames WHERE Title Like "%GI%" AND Title Like "%JOE%"
```

Returns a match where title = "Yu-Gi-Oh! Power of Chaos: Joey the Passion".

I know only matching full words wont completely resolve the issue, but it will hugely increase accuracy. What can i do to return what i want rather than this.

Comment: Add ` ` blanks between `%` and the actual word, like `'% word %'`?

Comment: what if the word is at the end of the string. 'GI JOE' wont math % JOE % will it?

Comment: Use a regex with word boundary: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RLIKE`, the regular expression version of `LIKE` to get more flexibility with your matching.

```
SELECT ID from VideoGames 
    WHERE Title RLIKE "[[:<:]]GI[[:>:]]" AND Title RLIKE "[[:<:]]JOE[[:>:]]"
```

The `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` markers are word boundaries marking the start and and of a word respectively. You could build a single regex rather than the `AND` but I have made this match your original question.